# Issue while Creating Latitudes-Lines on Globe using WhirlyGlobeComponet

Tags: ipad, cocoa-touch, ios6, opengl-es

I am working on WhirlyGlobe component tester application (great framework for globe app in ios  by mousebird team)and trying to create Latitudes and longitudes. I have created longitudes on globe using the method : `- (void)addGreatCircles:(LocationInfo *)locations len:(int)len stride:(int)stride offset:(int)offset`

and assigning the values as in the array :`LocationInfo locations[NumLocations]` **but when i try to create latitudes on the globe** by giving the coordinates in the as:

```
LocationInfo locations[NumLocations] = {
{"twenty five",0, 180},
{"twenty six",0, -10}
 // {"three",30,180.0},
 //  {"four",30,0},
// {"five",60, 180},
 //{"six",60, 0},
}
```

and son on... i am just able to get half the latitude Line on the globe. I do not know why this issue is coming up.Is this due to OpenGL  or what.Somebody please help me do it correctly.
the screenshot when i give starting points(0,-180) end point(0,0) comes up like shown in IMAGES- 1,2:

IMAGE-1
[image]

IMAGE-2
[image]

and what i need is that the complete latitude Line to be drawn on the Globe .Using  start point(0,0) to end point(0,360)  gives me  a blank output(no line drawn on the globe).
I have tried with Start point(0,10) end point (0,-10) so that line covers complete globe but no success yet.Please help guys!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you'll want to move to the develop branch on github.  That's version 2.2 which is just about to be released.

I've added an example in the test app that does exactly this.

[image]

Here's how we pull that off.

```
- (void)addLinesLon:(float)lonDelta lat:(float)latDelta color:(UIColor *)color
{
    NSMutableArray *vectors = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *desc = @{kMaplyColor: color, kMaplySubdivType: kMaplySubdivSimple, kMaplySubdivEpsilon: @(0.001), kMaplyVecWidth: @(4.0), kMaplyDrawPriority: @(1000)};
    // Longitude lines
    for (float lon = -180;lon < 180;lon += lonDelta)
    {
        MaplyCoordinate coords[3];
        coords[0] = MaplyCoordinateMakeWithDegrees(lon, -90);
        coords[1] = MaplyCoordinateMakeWithDegrees(lon, 0);
        coords[2] = MaplyCoordinateMakeWithDegrees(lon, +90);
        MaplyVectorObject *vec = [[MaplyVectorObject alloc] initWithLineString:coords numCoords:3 attributes:nil];
        [vectors addObject:vec];
    }
    // Latitude lines
    for (float lat = -90;lat < 90;lat += latDelta)
    {
        MaplyCoordinate coords[5];
        coords[0] = MaplyCoordinateMakeWithDegrees(-180, lat);
        coords[1] = MaplyCoordinateMakeWithDegrees(-90, lat);
        coords[2] = MaplyCoordinateMakeWithDegrees(0, lat);
        coords[3] = MaplyCoordinateMakeWithDegrees(90, lat);
        coords[4] = MaplyCoordinateMakeWithDegrees(+180, lat);
        MaplyVectorObject *vec = [[MaplyVectorObject alloc] initWithLineString:coords numCoords:5 attributes:nil];
        [vectors addObject:vec];
    }

    latLonObj = [baseViewC addVectors:vectors desc:desc];
}
```

WhirlyGlobe-Maply 2.2 adds a few tricks to vector rendering and subdivision.  You can now tell the toolkit to subdivide lines up to an epsilon to make them acceptable.  We can also render one thing on top of another without worrying about z buffering.  So there you go, it's pretty easy now.

The only real trickery here is that we have to break the lines into pieces.  We need at least three points or the subdivision logic will just detect a degenerate case.  The 5 point lines for latitude works some error test logic.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.I will definitely start working on the develop branch.check by adding the above code .Do i need to add this code to TestViewController directly and call this method where i need ?Hope to see the changes in the new 2.2 build real soon.One morw issue i am facing is with tap on the callout/overlay view.its not accepting the tap on the cross button what should i do for that . i have added the screenshot depicting in the above question itself.

Comment: image 5 shows the issue i am facing.need a piece of advice on this issue too.Thanks !!

Comment: I don't know what's up with your callout.  You might look at this: https://github.com/mousebird/WhirlyGlobe/issues/29

Comment: Can you please explain it in more detail on where i need to make that change as suggected in the issue given by you.is it in testviewcontroller or in TapDelegate.mm or in some eagleview file?? i had gone through this:https://github.com/mousebird/WhirlyGlobe/issues/5 but it doenot conclude to anything substantial..

Comment: I have not run into this problem myself, so I don't know quite what he was doing there.  I have had apps that did respond to taps in overlaid views, so I'm not really clear on why this happens.